# Excluding an area of the DOM on addEventListener

Tags: javascript

I would like to have an event to trigger when clicking on a box, and a different one when clicking on anyplace less that box. Here's the code:

```
<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
        document.querySelector("#demo").addEventListener("mouseover", funcion);
        document.querySelector("#demo").addEventListener("click", funcion2);
        document.querySelector("#demo").addEventListener("mouseout", funcion3);
        document.body.querySelector("#demo").addEventListener("click", funcion4, false);
        function funcion() {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "Mouse encima!<br>";
        }
        function funcion2() {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "Click dentro<br>";
        }
        function funcion3() {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "Mouse fuera!<br>";
        }
        function funcion4() {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "Click fuera<br>";
        }
        document.querySelector("#demo").addEventListener("click", function(e) {e.stopPropagation();}, true);
    </script>
</body>
```

"Tecnically" that should solve it, though i am getting the reverse solution I am looking for, it triggers both events (in & out) when clicking over the box, and none of the events when clicking out of it. I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an event listener to the `document` itself and detect the real target of the event from there.

```js
var box = document.getElementById('demo');

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target === box) {
    console.log('Clicking on the box');
  } else {
    console.log('Clicking outside of the box');
  }
});
```

```html
<p id="demo">This is the box!</p>
```

Comment: How a can include in box a child elements?